# Javascript Rouding in For statement

Tags: javascript, rounding, conditional-statements

I have this line:

```
for (var j = 0; j<1; j = (j + 0.1).toPrecision(1))
```

I'm trying to set up this statement so I get 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 up to the number 1.

At the moment I get 0, 0.1 and then nothing as if the result goes straight passed 1,

Simply using j = j + 0.1 produces rounding errors and I need the precise decimal place.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503716/why-does-toprecision-return-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this... When you use toPrecision its not number any more so it fails after the first iteration.

```
for (var j = 0; j<1; j = (parseFloat(j) + 0.1).toPrecision(1))
```

Answer (score 2):

It's better to do

```
for (var jj = 0; jj < 10; ++ jj) {
   var j = jj / 10;
   ...
}
```

if you need precision.