# Why parseFloat in javascript returns string type for me?

Tags: javascript, string, types, numbers, parsefloat

I searched and only found this one related to my question, but not exactly the same, as I'm using toFixed rather than toPrecision.
[Why does toPrecision return a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503716/why-does-toprecision-return-a-string)

Here is my code

```
var oldv = parseFloat(document.getElementById('total').textContent).toFixed(2);
alert(typeof oldv); // returns string
var testv = parseInt(document.getElementById('total').textContent);
alert(typeof testv); // returns number
```

I need further math steps, so string type messed up...
Why? How to solve? TIA

Comment: [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) and [`toPrecision`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision) both return strings. Please read the documentation. _“How to solve?”_ — depends on what your goal is.

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned in docs, [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) returns

> A string representing the given number using fixed-point notation

In case you need to use the returned result as a number, you can use built-in object [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number):

```js
var oldv = parseFloat(Math.PI).toFixed(2);

console.log( oldv );
console.log( typeof oldv ); // returns string

var num = Number(oldv);
console.log( num );
console.log( typeof num );  // returns number
```

Comment: This is confusing behavior to me, `toFixed` should return a `Number`.

Comment: Yeah you’d think it would return a number but not, you have to use number or do parseFloat twice like ‘parseFloat(parseFloat(“1738382.274838”).toFixed(2))`. Took me all day to figure this out

Answer (score 6):

The Number.prototype.toFixed() function is supposed to return a string type as per the documentation [found here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).

If you need to perform further arithmetic with the number you can coerce it back into numeric form using the Unary plus operator before the variable name (+) documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) like so:

```
var oldv = parseFloat(document.getElementById('total').textContent).toFixed(2);

alert(typeof oldv); // Returns string

alert(typeof +oldv); // Returns number
```